# Is there a standard way to know if a javascript library is compatible with the browser or node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I want to use `someLibrary` in my front end.

Maybe behind the scenes `someLibrary` uses a node only module like `crypto`, making it unuseable out of the box in the front end.

Is there a standard convention for knowing if a module is "front end only", "node only" or both ?

Comment: Read the library documentation?

Comment: You call that a "standard convention" ?

Comment: The official documentation would be the most logical place to start looking

Comment: Who would impose any sort of standard, let alone enforce it? Literally anybody on the planet can post a library on GitHub.

Comment: Why not use a convention that indicates what runtime the library is compatible with ?

Comment: there are probably thousands of different runtime configs that can be used, including custom implemented ones so front end modules can be used in node and vice versa

Comment: If you use NPM, then there is a convention,.  Inside package.json, the entry point instead of been `main`, can be set to `browser`,  I assume if it's intended for both, you set both to be the same.   Now, the question is how many NPM lib's, fill this in?..

Comment: A quick look at some packages in NPM that should be browser, like `react-router-dom`,  `bootstrap`, neither of these have the `browser` entry point set, so the answer to the above question, there is a convention, but nobody seems to use it.. :)